# Search filter selected quantity validation in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, validation

I have a set of drop down lists plus 2 textboxes as my filter fields in an ASP.net (C#) data search page. I would like to find a way to validate the selected filters so that the user will have to provide minimum 2 search filters. Meaning user will have to select at least 1 drop down and provide text for one textbox or select 2 drop downs.

Which is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use RequiredfieldValidator?

Comment: In a search filter you cannot force the user to select a value. I need to check the COUNT of selected drop downs or typed textboxes and see if they meet the minimum which is 2 values.

Comment: Assign all your search drop downs a specific css class (make one up) loop through them and count the ones with a value?  Are you using jQuery?

Comment: Use javascript to check whether the dropdown and textbox has value or not, if do not match with minimum requirement then return false.

Comment: Dude, I know I have to check their values but the question is how? Checking them 1 by 1 doesn't make sense. There must be a way to validate if a value is selected. By the way all my drop downs have the first index selected which is "- SELECT -" (just an FYI)

Comment: @Jared Thanks that looks like a proper way to do it. I will try it out

Comment: Or maybe I can declare a filter count property in code behind and increase/decrease it's value based on drop down item selection? :|

Comment: I don't use code behinds, but would doing that cause a post? (all my coding is mvc framework based)

Comment: @Sev did my answer below solve your issue?

Comment: @Jared No it doesn't, I tried debugging with Chrome to see what is wrong with it but it looks like it's not stepping into CheckFilters() method for some reason. My breakpoints ain't working in that method.

Comment: What validation framework are you using?  Model annotations and jquery validation?  To do those checks you have to do an explicit call (not hard).  However, the code below does do exactly as it should.  There is some other issue if it's not functioning for you.

Comment: Sorry haven't been able to work on this during holidays. I need to dig deeper and see what's up with my code. I won't forget to mark your answer as correct one. :D thx I will keep you posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jQuery you could use it to do what you are referring to without needing to post to the server.

Here is a full test page I mocked up that will check the values.  As long as two or more of the `select` elements with the `SearchSelect` class have a value other then `null` or `""` the function will return true.  If not it will color the boxes red that aren't selected.  You could also display an error message letting them know they need to select another filter...or something to that extent.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function CheckFilters() {
                var count = 0;
                $('.SearchSelect').addClass('badSelect');
                $('.SearchSelect').each(function() {
                    var sl = $(this);
                    if (sl.val() != null && sl.val() !== "") {
                        count++;
                        sl.removeClass('badSelect');
                    }
                });
                if (count >= 2) {
                    $('.SearchSelect').removeClass('badSelect');
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#SubmitButton').click(function(e) {
                    if(!CheckFilters()) e.preventDefault();
                    else alert("Success"); // in your case this line will probably be excluded and you will probably do nothing which will allow the POST/GET request to process
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            .badSelect{
                border: 1px solid red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
        <select class="SearchSelect" id="One">
            <option value="">Select A Filter</option>
            <option value="hasValue">Has a Value</option>
        </select><br /> 
        <select class="SearchSelect" id="Two">
            <option value="">Select A Filter</option>
            <option value="hasValue">Has a Value</option>
        </select> <br /> 
        <select class="SearchSelect" id="Three">
            <option value="">Select A Filter</option>
            <option value="hasValue">Has a Value</option>
        </select> <br />
        <button type="button" id="SubmitButton">Submit</button></form>
    </body>
</html>
```